# SWTableViewCell's RightUtilityButton how to directly display when I click the table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

i hope SWTableViewCell's RightUtilityButton will direct display when i click(not drag) the table cell.

SWTableViewCell does not seem to provide this interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `showRightUtilityButtonsAnimated:` method.I am using example code given.Replace `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and change `UMTableViewCell` to `YourCellClassName`

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cell selected at index path %ld:%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"selected cell index path is %@", [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]);


    if (!tableView.isEditing) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    //if you want to hide other cell which are opened first
    for (UMTableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells]) {

        [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
    }

    UMTableViewCell *cell = (UMTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell showRightUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];


}
```